# Disable UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete for certain cell

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a tableview and I want to display `UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete` but not for all of them. Based on the condition, for some cell's I would want to show `popover` without delete button style.

In my current implementation, when I swipe to delete I could still able to see both `UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete` and `popover`.

I wonder how could I able to achieve only see `popover` when user swipe right to left without `UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete`?

```
self.tableView.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = NO;


-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if([GlobalFunctions isComboItem:itemId])
    {
        // Show popover --> done
        // hide UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete -->  ?? dont know   
    }
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        NSString *itemId = [(NSDictionary *)[sharedData.orderItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:kItemId];
        [GlobalFunctions deleteItemFromOrder:itemId];
        [self calculate];
    }
}
```

Comment: your question is not clear

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik, assume that there are several tablecells. And when user swipes from right to left, tableview cell will show delete button. But for some cells I want to show only popover without showing delete button.

Comment: can you add some additional code,

Comment: I already provided all the related code for tableview editing style delegate methods that I am using.

Answer (score 0):

```
If (indexpath.row > 5 ) {
 // editing is not allowed greater than five

} else {
 // 5,4,3,2,1 editing is allowed 
}
```

Try this